# Select shipping method from previous order and set it as default for next order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

I'd like to have an functionality that
select the last order shipping method & set that shipping method for the next order for user.
Is their any event , can be used to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

get the last order detail by `getlastitem()` and from that get the shipping method name value in variable and when new order is placed set its shipping method to this variable